# Detekt - Suppress an issue for a generated file

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lint, detekt

On Android, when using Jetpack Navigation SafeArgs, some classes are generated by the lib and those classes cause some issues like "ThrowsCount", "UseRequire" and "MaxLineLength".

Is there a way to exclude thoses classes from being analyzed by detekt?

I tried reading the documentation on [Suppressing Rules](https://detekt.dev/docs/introduction/suppressing-rules/), but it does not mention it.

If it helps, all those classes ends up with "FragmentArgs".